# How to link external JavaScript file to WordPress theme?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I can't link the external JavaScript file to my WordPress theme through the plugin. All I found is this way to attach a JavaScript file:

```
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('script-name-faizan-test', 'http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('script-name-faizan-test');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where have you put it? how do you know it's not working?

Answer (score 1):

[According to the WP Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script), the example gives extra parameters:

```
<?php wp_register_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer ); ?>
```

So:

```
function child_add_scripts() {
    wp_register_script(
        'google-analytics',
        'http://google.com/analytics/script.js',
        false,
        '1.0',
        true
    );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'google-analytics' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-include-javascript-and-css-in-your-wordpress-themes-and-plugins--wp-24321) out:

Note that your relative path may be different.

```
function wptuts_scripts_basic()
  {
  // Register the script like this for a plugin:
  wp_register_script( 'custom-script', plugins_url( 'http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video.js', __FILE__ ) );
  // or
  // Register the script like this for a theme:
  wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . 'http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video.js' ); 

  // For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the script:
  wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
  }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wptuts_scripts_basic' );
```